# How do I parse Android native trace files (cannot find tracedmdump)?

Tags: android

I have six trace files (qtrace.bb, qtrace.exc, qtrace.insn, qtrace.method, qtrace.pid, qtrace.static) and I looked online and it seems like I need to use tracedmdump to parse these trace files.

I downloaded Android 2.2 source code and built it. I looked at the directory shown below to find out tracedmdump binary but I could not find it.

```
 android-2.2/out/host/linux-x86/bin
```

So my question is how do I parse those trace files and if I need to use tracedmdump then where do I get the file ?

I typed code below to build Android source code:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
make -j4
```

Answer (score 1):

The tracedmdump is a shell method defined in envsetup.sh ,you can find it in android/build/envsetup.sh.
After run source build/envsetup.sh ,you can use this method then.